# Writing a Pyspark UDF that functions like the Python any function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'd like to write an `any_lambda` function that checks if any of the elements in an `ArrayType` column meet a condition specified by a lambda function.

Here's the code I have that's not working:

```
def any_lambda(f, l):
    return any(list(map(f, l)))

spark.udf.register("any_lambda", any_lambda)

source_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("jose", [1, 2, 3]),
        ("li", [4, 5, 6]),
        ("luisa", [10, 11, 12]),
    ],
    StructType([
        StructField("name", StringType(), True),
        StructField("nums", ArrayType(StringType(), True), True),
    ])
)

actual_df = source_df.withColumn(
    "any_num_greater_than_5",
    any_lambda(lambda n: n > 5, col("nums"))
)
```

This code raises `TypeError: Column is not iterable`.

How can I create an `any_lambda` function that works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Udf expects the arguments to be columns, a `lambda` function is not a column; What you might do is define `any_lambda` so that it takes a lambda function and return a `udf`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def any_lambda(f):
    @F.udf
    def temp_udf(l):
        return any(map(f, l))
    return temp_udf

source_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("jose", [1, 2, 3]),
        ("li", [4, 5, 6]),
        ("luisa", [10, 11, 12]),
    ],
    StructType([
        StructField("name", StringType(), True),
        StructField("nums", ArrayType(IntegerType(), True), True),
    ])
)

actual_df = source_df.withColumn(
    "any_num_greater_than_5",
    any_lambda(lambda n: n > 5)(col("nums"))
)

actual_df.show()
+-----+------------+----------------------+
| name|        nums|any_num_greater_than_5|
+-----+------------+----------------------+
| jose|   [1, 2, 3]|                 false|
|   li|   [4, 5, 6]|                  true|
|luisa|[10, 11, 12]|                  true|
+-----+------------+----------------------+
```

---

Or as commented by @Powers, to be explicit about the returned column type, we can specify the returned type in the `udf` like so:

```
def any_lambda(f):
    def temp_udf(l):
        return any(map(f, l))
    return F.udf(temp_udf, BooleanType())
```

Now the schema looks like:

```
actual_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nums: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |-- any_num_greater_than_5: boolean (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Awesome answer.  I deleted `@F.udf` and added `return F.udf(temp_udf, BooleanType())` to make  `any_num_greater_than_5` a boolean column.  In your answer, it's a string column.  Can you update your answer to show both options?

Comment: @Powers Good call. Edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Hi Psidom, Can you tell me how this line works......... any_lambda(lambda n: n > 5)(col("nums"))